# It takes more than 10 minutes to generate entities from database in IntelliJ IDEA. How can I improve the speed?

Tags: oracle, jpa, intellij-idea, jpa-buddy

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and JPA Buddy to generate entities from my database. However, every time I open an Entity from DB wizard, it takes a very very long time. Is it okay? Or something wrong with my database/IntelliJ IDEA or JPA Buddy?

My setup is:
Database: Oracle (~2000 tables)
IntelliJ IDEA: 2022.3.1
JPA Buddy: 2022.5.3

I have tried to recreate db connection and invalidate caches in the IntelliJ IDEA, same result.

Comment: This is impossible to answer. You have not shared any details of your setup/configuration and we do not have access to your hardware, network, etc. to work out what would be "okay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen due to a slow internet connection or many tables in the database (probably it is your case, 2000 is great number). Also, some database drivers are not showing their best side in this matter. The one way you can speed up your development process – is a "schema cache" option from JPA Buddy (1). Using it, you can generate the data model snapshot once and then use its local copy.

[image]

Just don't forget to refresh it when the database gets changed (2).